# Problem with dragging and dropping elements in JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im trying to do some dragging and dropping on elements that is being created with the click of a button.

I have read a lot of post and watched at couple of videos, but i cant really find a solution.

I know i got a problem with the looping of the elements that is being created. Thats why i packed it in its own function so that it should run after its created.

I also think that the type i am trying to append is wrong here. thats why i made a little function to see the type.

I should mention that i am new to JS and just trying to build some to learn. I hope that you guys can help by posting a solution or maybe give me some hints. I might have missed some theory , as i am shelftaught.

Here is my code.

Its not made 100 mobile friendly! Look for a big round green button with a + for adding elements to the rows in the snippet! :-)

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
const workRow = document.querySelector('.workrow');
const workRows = document.querySelectorAll('.workrow');
const workTasks = document.querySelectorAll('.workrowtask');

const typeOf = () => {
    console.log(typeof workTasks)
};


btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    makePost(); 
    loopTasks();
    typeOf();
});

document.addEventListener('click', delPost);


function makePost() {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    const textnode = document.createTextNode('Hello World');
    div.appendChild(textnode);
    div.setAttribute('draggable', true);
    div.className = ('workrowtask');

    const delbtn = document.createElement('button');
    const textnodebtn = document.createTextNode('-');
    delbtn.appendChild(textnodebtn);
    delbtn.className = ('worktaskdelbtn');
    div.appendChild(delbtn);
    workRow.appendChild(div);
};  

function delPost(e) {
    if(e.target && e.target.className === 'worktaskdelbtn') {
        e.target.parentNode.remove();
    };
};

    
function loopTasks() {
    for (let t = 0; t < workTasks.length; t++) {
        const task = workTasks[t]
    
        task.addEventListener('dragstart', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log('dragstart')
        });
    
        task.addEventListener('dragend', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault()
            console.log('dragend')
        });
    }};
  


for (let r = 0; r < workRows.length; r++) {
    const rows = workRows[r]

    rows.addEventListener('dragover', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('dragover');
    });

    rows.addEventListener('dragenter', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('dragenter');
    });

    rows.addEventListener('drop', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('drop');

        rows.appendChild(workTasks)
    });

};
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: #393939;
}

.header {
    background-color: #00D189;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px 0px;
}

.worksection {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.workrow {
    width: 300px;
    background-color:white;
    height: 600px;
    border-radius: 30px 30px 0px 0px;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.workheader {
    width: 300px;
    padding: 20px 0px;
    border-radius: 30px 30px 0px 0px;
    background-color: #00D189;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

.buttonwrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.buttonwrapper button {
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #00D189;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin: 30px 15px 0px 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
}

.workrowtask {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: gray;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.worktaskdelbtn {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1214px) {
    .worksection {
      flex-flow: column;
      align-items: center;
    }

    .workrow {
        margin-bottom: 50px;
      }

    .worksection {
        position: relative;
    }

    .buttonwrapper {
        position: absolute;
        left: 30px;
        bottom: 300px;
    }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Drag&droptodo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header class="header">
        <h1>The Drag&Drop2Do</h1>
    </header>

    <section class="worksection">
        <div class="workrow">
            <div class="workheader">
                <p>Dagens opgaver</p>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="workrow">
            <div class="workheader">
                <p>Færdige opgaver</p>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="workrow">
            <div class="workheader">
                <p>Udskudte opgaver</p>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="workrow">
            <div class="workheader">
                <p>Afsluttet opgaver</p>
            </div>

        </div>

    </section>

    <div class="buttonwrapper">
        <button id="btn">+</button>
    </div>

    <script src="./javascript/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is in this:

```
rows.addEventListener('drop', (e) => {
    ................
    rows.appendChild(workTasks)
});
```

**workTasks** is empty.

On **dragenter** event you can set an attribute to the element and use it in the drop:

```
rows.addEventListener('drop', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var currTarsk = document.querySelector('.workrowtask[isdragging="true"]');
      currTarsk.removeAttribute('isdragging')
      rows.appendChild(currTarsk);
 });
```

The snippet:

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: #393939;
}

.header {
    background-color: #00D189;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px 0px;
}

.worksection {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.workrow {
    width: 300px;
    background-color: white;
    height: 600px;
    border-radius: 30px 30px 0px 0px;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.workheader {
    width: 300px;
    padding: 20px 0px;
    border-radius: 30px 30px 0px 0px;
    background-color: #00D189;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

.buttonwrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.buttonwrapper button {
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #00D189;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin: 30px 15px 0px 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
}

.workrowtask {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: gray;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.worktaskdelbtn {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1214px) {
    .worksection {
        flex-flow: column;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .workrow {
        margin-bottom: 50px;
    }

    .worksection {
        position: relative;
    }

    .buttonwrapper {
        position: absolute;
        left: 30px;
        bottom: 300px;
    }
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
    <h1>The Drag&Drop2Do</h1>
</header>

<section class="worksection">
    <div class="workrow">
        <div class="workheader">
            <p>Dagens opgaver</p>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="workrow">
        <div class="workheader">
            <p>Færdige opgaver</p>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="workrow">
        <div class="workheader">
            <p>Udskudte opgaver</p>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="workrow">
        <div class="workheader">
            <p>Afsluttet opgaver</p>
        </div>

    </div>

</section>

<div class="buttonwrapper">
    <button id="btn">+</button>
</div>
<script>
    const btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
    const workRow = document.querySelector('.workrow');
    const workRows = document.querySelectorAll('.workrow');
    const workTasks = document.querySelectorAll('.workrowtask');


    const typeOf = function () {
        console.log(typeof workTasks)
    };


    btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
        makePost();
        loopTasks();
        //typeOf();
    });

    document.addEventListener('click', delPost);

    function makePost() {
        const div = document.createElement('div');
        const textnode = document.createTextNode('Hello World');
        div.appendChild(textnode);
        div.setAttribute('draggable', true);
        div.className = ('workrowtask');

        const delbtn = document.createElement('button');
        const textnodebtn = document.createTextNode('-');
        delbtn.appendChild(textnodebtn);
        delbtn.className = ('worktaskdelbtn');
        div.appendChild(delbtn);
        workRow.appendChild(div);
    };

    function delPost(e) {
        if (e.target && e.target.className === 'worktaskdelbtn') {
            e.target.parentNode.remove();
        };
    };


    function loopTasks() {
        for (let t = 0; t < workTasks.length; t++) {
            const task = workTasks[t]
            task.addEventListener('dragstart', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            });
            task.addEventListener('dragend', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault()
            });
        }
    };
    for (let r = 0; r < workRows.length; r++) {
        const rows = workRows[r]
        rows.addEventListener('dragover', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });
        rows.addEventListener('dragenter', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.target.setAttribute('isdragging', true);
        });
        rows.addEventListener('drop', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var currTarsk = document.querySelector('.workrowtask[isdragging="true"]');
            currTarsk.removeAttribute('isdragging')
            rows.appendChild(currTarsk);
        });
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It helped alot and i learned something new :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function allowDrop(allowDropEvent) {
  allowDropEvent.target.style.color = 'blue';
  allowDropEvent.preventDefault();
}

function drag(dragEvent) {
  dragEvent.dataTransfer.setData('text', dragEvent.target.id);
  dragEvent.target.style.color = 'green';
}

function drop(dropEvent) {
  dropEvent.preventDefault();
  
  var data = dropEvent.dataTransfer.getData('text');
  dropEvent.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  
  document.getElementById('drag').style.color = 'black';
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

#div1 {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#div2 {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 2;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <span id="drag" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Drag me to the other box</span>
  </div>
  <div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
</div>
```

A simple example of the use of the HTML Drag and Drop API.

You can also check out the MDN Web Docs for:

- [HTML Drag and Drop API reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API)
- [JavaScript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)

If this doesn't help, please tell me.

Comment: thank you for the solution and the links. I got it to work out :-)

Answer (score 0):

I've removed unnecessary parts from your JavaScript code. Also changed CSS and HTML just for simplifying the answer.

Note: I removed `overflow:scroll`, because it looks weird in your example.

Here is working example:

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
const workRow = document.querySelector('.workrow');
const workRows = document.querySelectorAll('.workrow');
let counter = 0;

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  makePost();
});

function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  if (ev.target.className == 'workrow') {
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  }
}

function makePost() {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  const textnode = document.createTextNode('Hello World ' + counter);
  div.id = 'helloWorld' + counter;
  counter++;
  div.appendChild(textnode);
  div.setAttribute('draggable', true);
  div.className = 'workrowtask';

  const delbtn = document.createElement('button');
  const textnodebtn = document.createTextNode('-');
  delbtn.appendChild(textnodebtn);
  delbtn.className = 'worktaskdelbtn';
  div.appendChild(delbtn);

  delbtn.addEventListener('click', delPost);

  div.addEventListener('dragstart', drag);

  workRow.appendChild(div);
}

function delPost(e) {
  if (e.target && e.target.className === 'worktaskdelbtn') {
    e.target.parentNode.remove();
  }
}

for (let r = 0; r < workRows.length; r++) {
  const row = workRows[r]
  row.addEventListener('dragover', allowDrop);
  row.addEventListener('dragenter', allowDrop);
  row.addEventListener('drop', drop);
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #393939;
}

.header {
  background-color: #00D189;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 0px;
  display: none;
  /*!!!*/
}

.worksection {
  width: 100%;
  /*margin-top: 50px;*/
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.workrow {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 30px 30px 0px 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.workheader {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 20px 0px;
  border-radius: 30px 30px 0px 0px;
  background-color: #00D189;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.buttonwrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.buttonwrapper button {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #00D189;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  /*margin: 30px 15px 0px 0px;*/
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}

.workrowtask {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.worktaskdelbtn {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Drag&droptodo</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header class="header">
    <h1>The Drag&Drop2Do</h1>
  </header>

  <section class="worksection">
    <div class="workrow">
      <div class="workheader">
        <p>Dagens opgaver</p>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="workrow">
      <div class="workheader">
        <p>Færdige opgaver</p>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="workrow">
      <div class="workheader">
        <p>Udskudte opgaver</p>
      </div>

    </div>

  </section>

  <div class="buttonwrapper">
    <button id="btn">+</button>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```